# Android: add dynamically onClickListener on massive widgets

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Lets say I have these buttons : b1, b2, b3, b4, b5. I am searching how to do this:

```
ArrayList<Button> bAL = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    bAL.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.b+[i]));  //The expression should equal to R.id.b1 or R.id.b2 or..
    bAL.get(i).setOnclickListener(new View.onClickListener{...});
}
```

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: If you want do this in activity better way is to add onClick in xml. And write this one method in activity that will catch all button clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All **`ID's`** are **`integer`** so the simplest way is to put them in an **`integer array`** and use them, plus arrays are easy to manipulate (set / reset ids). In case you don't want to manipulate the ID array then mark it as `final` ( will add little for efficiency ).

```
       int ar[]={ R.id.button1,R.id.button2,R.id.button3 };

        ArrayList<Button> bAL = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
            bAL.add((Button) findViewById(ar[i])); 
            bAL.get(i).setOnclickListener(listener);  // have a listener and just use the refereance

        }

View.onClickListener  listener =new View.onClickListener(){
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Button> bAL = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    String buttonId = "b" + i;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonId, "id", getPackageName());
    bAL.add((Button) findViewById(resID));
    bAL.get(i).setOnclickListener(...);
}
```

That should do the trick. Try and google next time, a simple google of "findviewbyid string android" brought up loads of answers.